# .htaccess satisfy www/ssl rules before redirection

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect, https

I've looked through tens of articles regarding this but none of them has solved my issue and it continues to give me a headache.

Here's what I want to achieve:
1) I have an second domain name which needs redirecting to the main domain while keeping the rest of the URL,
2) All files should lose .php extension,
3) Force WWW,
4) Force HTTPS.

Now the problem is that my current .htaccess only works this way for the main domain and only if the WWW condition is met. Let me explain.

If I type in **domain1.com/page** or **domain2.com/page**, it will open **https:// www.domain1/2.com/page.php** but it should only be **/page** without .php.

If I type in **www.domain1.com/page**, it will open **https:// www.domain1.com/page** - Expected behaviour,
but if I type in **www.domain2.com/page**, it will open **https:// domain1.com/page.php**.

How can I make sure that any conbination of HTTP/HTTPS and WWW/non-WWW, domain1.com/domain2.com always redirects to **https:// www.domain1.com/page** ?

I'm also happy for any php code suggestions that I might put  the top of every .php file to automatically redirect to the extensionless version but would really love to understand why my .htaccess isn't working.

Here's the code:

```
## Main Rules
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Redirect Domain2.com to Main
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com/$1 [R,L]

## Remove .php Extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

## Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## Force WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the directives in the wrong order. Importantly, the rule that *appends* the `.php` extension via an internal rewrite (which you've labelled "Remove .php Extensions") should go at the end, *after* the external redirects. Your rewrite is appending `.php` to the requested URL, ie. `page` becomes `page.php` and *then* you are triggering an external redirect which naturally exposes the underlying filename.

However, your directives will result in multiple redirects and can be simplified. The last redirect, for instance, does not canonicalise the protocol (and replies on previous rules to have done this).

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404

## Main Rules
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Redirect Domain2.com to Main
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain1.com/$1 [R,L]

## Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## Force WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## Append .php Extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

If you have no intention of implementing HSTS then you should reverse the "Force HTTPS" and "Force WWW" rules in order to avoid an additional redirect when requesting `http://domain1.com/page`.

Note that your initial redirect from `domain2.com` to `domain1.com` is a 302 (temporary) redirect.

**UPDATE:** Note that `MultiViews` should also be disabled, if not already. For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

If MultiViews was enabled, then this would also result in the first redirect exposing the file extension since mod_negotiation would issue an internal subrequest for `page.php` *before* mod_rewrite processes the request. However, if `MultiViews` was enabled, then this would also mean that your final rewrite rule that appends the `.php` extension was effectively being bypassed (since the 2nd conditon would always fail, unless `page.php.php` existed.).

With MultiViews disabled then this highlights a potential bug with the final rewrite. In that a request for `/page/foo`, where `/page.php` exists as an actual file (as in your example) would result in a 500 internal server error due to a rewrite loop. To correct this, the final rewrite rule that appends the `.php` extension should be changed to the following:

```
## Append .php Extensions
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

(There's no need to check that the request is *not* a directory *and* is a file, since it can never be both.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this had no effect at all on what I want to achieve (still same - extensions exposed when URL typed in directly without www), so I don't believe the order was to blame.

Comment: You need to clear your browser cache. (301s are cached persistently by the browser.)

Comment: What "slight tweaks" did you have to make? ....Did you need to disable `MultiViews`?

Comment: ## Append .php Extensions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]